# Dismiss delegate for UIMenuElement Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, dismiss, uimenu

I have a UIMenu on my app and I want to detect when a user taps outside(dismiss) the UIMenu. But it seems like Apple does not support any delegates by default for this action.
Because when a user taps outside I want to change the image of the button.
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JffxZ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One rather hacky way I found, is to subclass `UIButton` and override `contextMenuInteractionWillEndFor`.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, willEndFor configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
        super.contextMenuInteraction(interaction, willEndFor: configuration, animator: animator)
        print("ending!")
    }
}
```

[`contextMenuInteractionWillEndFor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteractiondelegate/3375806-contextmenuinteraction) is the delegate method that is called when you dismiss a `UIMenu`, but if you are setting the button's `menu` property, the button itself will become the delegate of the `UIContextMenuInteraction`, and you can't set it to something else, which is why you have to subclass `UIButton`.

Compare this to when you are adding a context menu using `addInteraction`, where you have control over the `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate`.

Comment: works like a charm, that was all what I need, thx!